# PutItem into DynamoDB is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb

I have an EC2 instance which opens up a json file, reads each line and does a putItem operation into two tables.

Without the putItem operation, Golang parses a 67k line file in about 3 seconds.

With the putItem operation, it is processing 10k items every 5 minutes. The put operation into dynamodb is not being throttled. The WCUs and RCUs have been set accordingly. So Is there a reason that the putItem operation is holding up the code?

I assume that Golang is waiting for each put operation to succeed?

Still quite unsure, if anyone has done a mass insert into dynamodb using golang, then it would be helpful if you shedded some light on how you circumvented this.

Comment: There is a BatchWriteItem function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.BatchWriteItem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slowness comes from the fact that each insert has to do a full HTTP round trip to dynamo.

10k items in 5 mins is about 30ms per item, which is expected of an HTTP trip.

You can use a batch update, [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.BatchWriteItem)

In the docs, you have `BatchWriteItemInput`, which takes a `map[string][]*WriteRequest`.

```
type BatchWriteItemInput struct {
    // ... trimmed

    RequestItems map[string][]*WriteRequest

    ...
}
```

The `WriteRequest` model is a little odd, because its used for both `Delete` and `Put` operations, just ignore the `DeleteRequest *DeleteRequest` field.

It's important to note that there are some limits on the batch operation:

- You can't change the same item more than once in a batch request
- You must have more than 2 and fewer than 25 items in a batch
- Each item cannot be bigger than 400KB and the total batch cannot be bigger than 16MB.

Comment: Used a wrapper around BatchItemReq to process more than 25 items in parallel, speed went to about 1million/5seconds. Thanks for the explanation